# juju charm relation-joined hook not working?

Tags: juju

i have two charms and i want to build relationship and get details from server charm(server charm and application charm).Now i can add relationship.But it is not running application-relation-joined in my hooks.For my understanding after add relationships it should be run.But i have put logs to check whether relation-joined hooks are  runnning or not.it is not printing log files.Please anyone tell me littile bit more about after adding relationship how `-relation-joined`,`-relation-changed`,`-relation-departed` and `-relation-broken` are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was not running when run-server in start(my server is `jetty`) so **it holds the hook and it will not continue the other hooks**.I resolve problem.After adding relationship i have start the server.it works.It means i didn't run server in `start` hook i run the server `-relation-changed` hook file.